# Toast com duração específica

Tags: java, android

Como colocar esse Toast para durar apenas alguns segundos? Por exemplo, 10 segundos.

```
if (mEmail.equals(email) && mPassword.equals(password)) {


                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
                    intent.putExtra("result", result);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }

                else {


                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Email ou senha inválido(s)",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            }



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }}}}
```

Comment: por favor, marcar a resposta correta caso tenha lhe ajudado.

Answer (score 2):

Isso não pode ser feito. Para mostrar por um tempo menor que Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, você deve cancelá-lo após o tempo desejado. Algo como:

```
   final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This message will disappear     in half second", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

        Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   toast.cancel(); 
               }
        }, 500);
```

Comment: Obrigado,funcionou corretamente !

Comment: Muito bom!
Por favor, marque como resposta correta caso tenha te ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Para o Toast existem apenas 2 flags: `LENGTH_SHORT` e `LENGTH_LONG`. Ou seja, sao valores já definidos.

Para atender o que voce precisa, precisamos fazer algo mais do jeito brasileiro. Seria algo assim:

```
private Toast mToastToShow;
public void showToast(View view) {

int toastDurationInMilliSeconds = 10000;
mToastToShow = Toast.makeText(this, "Hello world, I am a toast.", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

CountDownTimer toastCountDown;
 toastCountDown = new CountDownTimer(toastDurationInMilliSeconds, 1000) 
 {
  public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mToastToShow.show();
  }
  public void onFinish() {
     mToastToShow.cancel();
     }
 };

mToastToShow.show();
toastCountDown.start();
}
```

Ou seja, tu vai ter um contador de x tempo (10 segundos no caso), que vai ficar disparando toast durante esse tempo. Assim que terminar, ele vai cancelar o toast e parar de exibi-lo. É um truque.

Caso queira utilizar uma `lib`, que eu utilizo em meus projetos, que facilita isso pode utilizar [essa aqui](https://github.com/rakshithsj30/UtilsPlus) que possui o método

`UtilsPlus.getInstance().toast("Hello World!", 5);`

onde
*5* é o valor em segundos para o tempo de exibiçao.

Answer (score 0):

Toasts têm apenas duas durações possíveis: [`Toast.LENGTH_SHORT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#LENGTH_SHORT) e [`Toast.LENGTH_LONG`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#LENGTH_LONG). Esses valores são tratados como sinalizadores e não como durações. Não é possível manualmente escolher um tempo exato de duração.